# Using multiple directives on same page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use same directive multiple times in a page, and i know that i need to make isolated scope but i didnt managed to do it.
Can someone give me some tips?

This is my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ui.instagram">

<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Libs -->
    <script src="js/custom/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <!-- version 1.2.19 -->
    <script src="js/custom/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!--Custom Directives-->
    <script src="js/custom/ui-instagram.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div ui-instagram user-id='xxxxx' client-id="xxxxxx"></div>
    <img ng-repeat="gram in grams" ng-attr-src="{{ gram.images.standard_resolution.url }}"></img>

    <div ui-instagram user-id='xxxxx' client-id="xxxxxx"></div>
    <img ng-repeat="gram in grams" ng-attr-src="{{ gram.images.standard_resolution.url }}"></img>

</body>

</html>
```

This is directive code:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('ui.instagram', []).service('Instagram', function ($http) {
        return {
            get: function (id, clientId, cb) {
                var URL;
                URL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" + id + "/media/recent/?client_id=" + clientId + "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
                return $http.jsonp(URL).success(function (resolution) {
                    return cb(resolution.data);
                });
            }
        };
    }).directive('uiInstagram', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                userId: '@userId',
                clientId: '@clientId'
            },
            controller: function ($scope, $attrs, Instagram) {
                $scope.grams = [];
                return Instagram.get($attrs.userId, $attrs.clientId, function (grams) {
                    return $scope.grams = grams;
                });
            }
        };
    });

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would increase the responsibility of the directive up by a level, and make it responsible for rendering the images, rather than have your controllers view do that:

Change your directive to:

```
.directive('uiInstagram', function (Instagram) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                userId: '=',
                clientId: '='
            },           
            templateUrl:'instagramTpl.html'
            link: function (scope,element, attrs) {
                scope.grams = [];
                Instagram.get(scope.userId, scope.clientId, function (grams) {
                    scope.grams = grams;
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

And the `instagramTpl.html`:

```
 <img ng-repeat="gram in grams" ng-src="{{ gram.images.standard_resolution.url }}"></img>
```

And change your service to:

```
 return {
            get: function (id, clientId, cb) {
                var URL;
                URL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" + id + "/media/recent/?client_id=" + clientId + "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
                $http.jsonp(URL).success(function (resolution) {
                     cb(resolution.data);
                });
            }
        };
```

Usage inside your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
 <div ui-instagram user-id='user.id' client-id="user.clientId//or whatever"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In view part idea is to write different ids like this <div ng-repeat="user in users">
 <div ui-instagram user-id='8263704' client-id="82637048263704"></div>
</div>

Comment: Well why do you get a blank page? Any errors? Try posting a plunk.

Comment: Sorry, can't tell much without a plunk or a fiddle

Comment: and what exactly should you pass in for client-id and user-id? can you give some values.

Comment: [heres a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5GfB/), I'd be grateful if you could accept my answer if it answered your question :)

Comment: if i am not mistaken this shows pictures from only one user

Comment: and yeah dont worry i will give you rep

Comment: I made a typo in the controller, `clientTd` should be `clientId`.

Comment: oh yeah i see now, thank you for your help. so this needed a controller to be able to use it multiple times, now i understand